# Recursive Batch script for calculating pow

Tags: batch-file, recursion, cmd, pow

I'm crashing my head tring to understand where the error is in this Batch script, used for calculating the pow of a given number through recursion of the function "pow", as many times as the order of the pow(in the script is set the pow o 3^3)

The errors I got are: 
"order1" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
"base22" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Both errors are shown in sequence rows, numerous times until the statement "batch recursion exceeds stack limits" compairs stopping the recursion.
Someone's able to find the error in the script?

```
@echo off

set /a base1=3
set /a base2=3
set /a order=3
call :pow %base1%, %base2%, %order%
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% 

:pow
set /a base11=%~1   
set /a base22=%~2
set /a order1=%~3
order1=order1-1
base22=base11*base22
if %order1% GTR 0 (call :pow %base11%, %base22%, %order1%)
else(echo the calculated pow is %base22%)
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: @pjs, actually they are missing the `SET /A` as part of the command.  You don't need percent symbols for the variable when using `SET /A`

Comment: @Squashman Thanks.  More familiar with shell scripts, but lines 13 and 14 certainly looked suspect to me.

Comment: WOPR, your syntax for the `IF ELSE` is not correct.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?`.  It will show you the correct syntax for using `IF ELSE`.

Comment: I appreciated your help guys...special mention goes to Squashman, infact, all I had to do was adding SET /A in the two lines used for manipulate order1 and calculate the pow base22, beside adjusting the syntax for the if else construct

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would consider doing it in a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "num1=3"
Set "num2=3"
Set "expo=3"

Set/A base=num1*num2
Set "rslt=1"
For /L %%A In (1 1 %expo%) Do Set/A rslt*=base
Echo %rslt%
Pause
```

*Just be aware that you will be severely limited by maximum 32-bit integers.*